# How to design Digital logic gate using TFET logic?

Tags: digital-logic, mosfet, low-power, cmos, semiconductors

In my recent project, I need to design digital logic gates using TFET instead of CMOS logic.
Can someone Suggest any simulator or procedure which support design using TFET logic?

Comment: You should probably read the TFET papers and/or ask in academic/research circles. Not many people here doing that. Probably this one in particular: http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TCSII.2009.2035274

Comment: I apologize as I seem to be late and you are probably already past this, but I gave a suggestion answer for future people.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem there is a simulator called NEMO5
I will also link in the paper which called this out...
https://www.e3s-center.org/pubs/187/Huang_David.pdf